# Do permanent negative levels take away class abilities?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Lets say I am a level 20 monk of the four winds and I have just been resurrected by my 20th level ability. Now, since this ability gives two negative levels, would my 20th level ability still function?

Comment: Particularly the first answer, which explains the effects of negative levels (both temporary and permanent) in Pathfinder.